# How do I make each one of grid links point to an absolute url of my site

Tags: html

- Image1
- Image2
- Image3 me

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement to meet the standards of this site.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.